# Allegorical book about a Spanish knight who talks into his helmet

Tags: story-identification, books, christian

This was a book I read in the early to mid 90's.  I believe it was older than that, though.
It was an allegorical (specifically a "Christian" allegory) story about a knight who was on a quest for something.

This knight was similar to a Spanish conquistador and when he had a moral dilemma or a tough choice to make he would lower his metal helmet over his face and ask questions, and the echo of his question would bounce around and rearrange the words to form an answer to his question.
I remember thinking this book was hysterical and would love to find it again.

Comment: Are you talking about Don Quixote?  I haven't read it all.

Comment: I don't think so.  I think this book was specifically targeted at young adults.

Comment: The `fantasy` tag is banned on this site, notice that your question actually has `epic-fantasy` which doesn't apply to either of your questions. `story-identification` would be the proper tag. But is this actually a fantasy story? Your description makes it sound like it's a moral tale without any supernatural element.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it was a fantasy with magical creatures and things, but it was also a moral tale too.

Comment: You might want to look here to see if it's one of the books influenced by Don Quixote - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_influenced_by_Don_Quixote

Comment: I immediately thought of Italo Calvino's Non-existent Knight (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nonexistent_Knight), but after reading your question in its entirety I no longer think it's that. I thought I would leave the link here anyway.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because when asked, the querent could provide no evidence that this is Fantasy, or Sci-Fi.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're talking about "[The Nonexistent Knight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nonexistent_Knight)", the knight with the empty armor.

> The protagonists of this novel are two paladins of Charlemagne: the titular non-existent knight, named Agilulf (he is in fact a lucid empty armor) and an inexperienced and passionate young man, Rambaldo. The latter, having arrived at the camp of paladins at the beginning of the novel, wants to avenge his father's death, caused by the Argalif Isoarre; Agilulf instead fights for duty, convinced of his faith, with a value that is admired by all the paladins, but also with a remarkable sense of duty, of precision in controlling the progress of the duties of others and their duties, for which the fellow soldiers find it as capable as it is unpleasant. During the move that Charlemagne made with his paladins to clash with the enemies, they met Gurdulù, a vagabond who let himself be guided by instinct without thinking, and who will be assigned as a squire to Agilulf by order of Charlemagne.

Comment: Nope!  But thanks for the suggestion.  This book was specifically a comedic allegory and written for young adults.